# Once the user has input an amount, the amount shall be multiplied by "s2"

Tags: javascript, html

//after the user has input an amount, the calculate button will redirect it to the function and suppose to have an answer. I get the first two selections right but then it seems to get stuck. s1 and s2 are working properly but the rest no. S1 shows the main selection and s2 shows the sub selection:.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function populate(s1,s2)
        {
            var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
            var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
            s2.innerHTML = "";
            if(s1.value == "Chevy")
            {
                var optionArray = ["|","1000|Camaro","2000|Corvette","3000|Impala"];//The | means a blank space, camaro is the label, Camaro is the value, ex. value 1000 and corvette is the label
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Dodge")
            {
                var optionArray = ["|","4000|Avanger","5000|Challengere","6000|Charger"];
            }
            else if(s1.value == "Ford")
            {
                var optionArray = ["|","7000|Mustang","8000|Shelby"];
            }
            for(var option in optionArray)//the options within the optionArray
            {
                var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");//in tha variable pair is stored both value and label
                var newOption = document.createElement("option");// option in the bracket is used to create new options or you can insert divs paragraph etc
                newOption.value = pair[0];//pair 0 gives the value
                newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];//pair 1 gives the label
                s2.options.add(newOption);
            }
        }
    function calculateTotal() {
  var model = document.getElementById("slct2");
  var modelValue = model.options[model.selectedIndex].value;
  var amount = document.querySelector('input[name="amount"]').value;

  return modelValue * amount;
}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
        <hr>
        Choose Car Make:
        <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
            <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
        </select>
        <hr>
        Choose Car Model:
        <select id="slct2" name="slct2">

        </select>
        <label>Amount<input type="numbers" name="amount" size="1"/></label>
        <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
        <input type="button" name="Calculate" value="Calculate" id="Calculate" onclick="populate(s1,s2)">
<label>Total amount<input type="numbers" name="answer"  size="10"/></label>
        </body>
        </html>
```

//I have inserted the function calculateTotal as stated by you but still can`t get a result in it. I have added a box where the result can be shown as labeled "Total amount"

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: jcubic has fixed it for you, but please make note for next time.

Comment: Thanks my friend but I am new to this site.

Comment: All the more reason to pay attention to the various bits of help and such the site offers you, and to take particular care when posting.

Comment: Is there any videos such as you tube to show/help how to post a proper question as this would help me much more rather than words?

Comment: Camaro value is 1000, in your code, but you've mentioned 10000 (guess it is a typo... Separate functions for creating selection drop downs, and calculation, e.g. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ebb23h8e/

Comment: Thanks my friend exactly what I wanted. But there is a small problem as I don`t want it an alert answer and i have added a box, <label>Total amount<input type="numbers" name="answer"  size="10"/></label>. How can I replace the alert with the above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3715674,  http://jsfiddle.net/ebb23h8e/1/ something like this. Also, input type is not numbers(plural), it should be number(singular).

Comment: Great works fine and perfect. One last question. I want that my website looks a bit more professional so I was wondering if it is possible to create an automatic answer instead of clicking the button. While the user is inputting the amount increase automatically. I have never implemented any. Is that possible or is it difficult? I am on my first year in java.

Comment: Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/ebb23h8e/2/ you can add onkeyup event handler to desired field (amount in this case): onkeyup="calculate()" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup

Comment: It is getting extremely interesting. I have to make 10 of the same codes in my website and what I am doing is just copy and save the functions with different names.(Just include a number after). The reason why is because let say a user wants 10 Camaro, 5 avenger and 4 shelby. and at the end I want to know how much cars does the user wants. How can I store all the answers and then get them all plus in a one separate one great total answer but I still want to keep all the answers how they are now. Just add another  function that add all the functions.

Comment: Is it possible to make a for loop rather than create multiple functions to have a cleaner code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function calculateTotal() {
  var model = document.getElementById("slct2");
  var modelValue = model.options[model.selectedIndex].value;
  var amount = document.querySelector('input[name="amount"]').value;

  return modelValue * amount;
}
```

I'm not sure where you want to put the output of this function or when you want to trigger it, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: I have inserted a label called "Total amount" to get an answer. I have inserted the function as stated by you under my main function but still can`t get the result in the "Total amount".